# Grep all NON-readonly files

Tags: unix, grep

In my Mac, when I open terminal, how would I go about listing all files within a directory and subs that are NON-readonly?

The readonly part is the one i'm not sure on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define or decide what 'NON-readonly' means.  Is a file that's executable not readonly?  What about a file that has no permissions (it isn't readonly, but it isn't readable either).

Second, use [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) with appropriate options (`-perm`, maybe `-maxdepth`) to generate the list of files, and then execute `grep`:

```
 find . -type f ...other controls... -exec grep -e '36 inches' {} +
```

The `+` is a recent but useful innovation.  If it is not available, you could use GNU `find` and its `-print0` piped to GNU `xargs -0` instead, but GNU `find` supports the `+` notation anyway.  If you don't have GNU `find` and GNU `xargs`, you may have to use plain `-print` and `xargs`, but that doesn't properly handle file names with oddball characters (spaces, newlines in particular) in the names.

Comment: Maybe use xargs to save PIDs: `find . -type f ...other controls... | xargs grep -e '36 inches'`.

Comment: Read up on the `+` option to [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html); it saves on processes without using `xargs`.